# KDE ignoring changes made to monitor position/rotation

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde

I've been having all sorts of issues with Xorg, so this may have been self inflicted.

I currently have two monitors, a 1280x1024 (we'll call it A) and a 1600x1200 (B) that is rotated 90 to the right (portrait mode).  A is physically left of B.  Currently, both monitors display the same image.  When I try to either shift B to the right or rotate it in "Size and Orientation - KDE control Module" and hit "Apply", the changes that I made are reverted back to what they were.  The only thing that I've been able to do successfully is to change the resolution of B to 1600x1200 but that just makes the activity bar disappear from A (logically below it's visible display).

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with KDE.  And all the problems started when I upgraded my kernel to 3.10.

This is what my desktop currently looks like ,
[image]

And this is what I want my desktop to look like ,
[image]

Any ideas why my settings are not being saved?

Comment: @Braiam Updated the question to add pictures

Comment: Did you press "Save as Default"?

Comment: I have and still nothing changes.  I have even seen only some of the changes take effect.  Say, if I rotate 180 degrees, that will be applied but a 90 degree rotation won't be.